# Playscape SDK 1.6 and Unity 4.5.5 show error when builds two file: APK and OBB

Tags: unity-game-engine, playscape

It shows error 'An error occured while applying post-build logic: Object reference not set to an instance of an object' when it builds two-file android build: APK + OBB.

Playscape's ApkCreator try to extract config file 'assets/playscape/PlayscapeConfig.xml' from APK. But config is inside .OBB file.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're currently do not support APK expansion files (for applications that are bigger than 50MB). We expect to support this functionality in a future version. Can you contact me directly so can discuss your game specifically. sharonh@playscape.com

Thanks,
Sharon

Comment: Thanks. I'll contact you soon.